# Count records by month & type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with this schema:

```
OccuredDate (date)     TypeID (int)
2014-1-1               1
2014-1-2               1
2014-2-5               4
2015-5-23              2
2015-6-3               3
```

…it has thousands of rows comprised of dates & typeIDs, spanning years.

So that I can plot this to a charting component, I’m trying to build a query that for a given year **1)** returns one row per-month that **2)** counts the total number of TypeID instances for the given TypeIDs. The charting component prefers columns for the type counts.

So for "2014" it would look like this:

```
MonthDate    TypeOne    TypeTwo    TypeThree    TypeFour
2014-1-1     2          0          0            0
2014-2-1     0          0          0            1
```

or:

```
Year    Month    TypeOne    TypeTwo    TypeThree    TypeFour
2014    Jan       2          0          0            0
2014    Feb       0          0          0            1
```

Spent most of the night on it but no luck. Is there some dark SQL magic that will do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using pivot, with something like this:

```
SELECT OccuredDate, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(
    SELECT OccuredDate, TypeID FROM Table1) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    count(TypeID) FOR TypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
```

And per month version:

```
SELECT 
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, OccuredDate), 0) as Month,
  sum([1]) as [1], 
  sum([2]) as [2], 
  sum([3]) as [3], 
  sum([4]) as [4]
FROM
(
    SELECT OccuredDate, TypeID FROM Table1) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    count(TypeID) FOR TypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
group by 
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, OccuredDate), 0)
```

You can test this in SQL Fiddle: [daily](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60f5e0/2) and [monthly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60f5e0/6)

Edit: Rewrote the monthly SQL

Comment: The operator in pivot should be sum because it's calculating the counts, fixed it + new link for SQL Fiddle.

Comment: maybe I'm not describing it well, because your new SQL Fiddle (monthly) is still showing incorrect counts. it correctly counts the number of rows for the given month, but it doesnt correctly map them to the four possible TypeID columns. for ex: 2015-Jun has 4 rows, but in the Fiddle they're all counted under the "4" column, rather than spread across columns "1" (x1), "2" (x1) and "3" (x2).

Comment: @mdelvecchio Not my day it seems, well, at least now it's fixed, you'll of course have to do the pivot first and sum after that to get the correct figures

Comment: Instead of pivot you can also use sum + case, something like: sum(Case when TypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Type1, sum(case when TypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end)...